# select column from table with only matched data from another table

Tags: sql, select

I need to select 2 column from table with matched data from another table or cell be null ,

```
table 1 named "emp" contain emp_name ,emp_id
table 2 named "salary" contain emp_sal, emp_id
```

I need to create select query
have all emp_name, emp_id and emp_sal (for only the employees will take sale) or be Null

thanks for help now ((((update ))))

first thanks for help
i used

```
SELECT emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name,salary.emp_sal FROM emp LEFT JOIN salary ON emp.emp_id = salary.emp_id;
```

it work but with a lot of duplication and i need to make this query with day ...

i create another table named "day" i need query appear  day i entered in this table

this table have only one column and i record ((day user entered and saved in "day.user_day"))

i need to link this three tables
 together

and lets make it easy we will change salary to attendance ...

i need to query all names and id in date and apear all employee what ever thy have time or not

like when i search only in day 4/8/2014

```
name     id  time
john     1    04/08/2014 06:00 
man      2    null
scsv     3    04/08/2014 07:00
```

Comment: It would be great if you mention which database platform you are using, though for this specific case its probably going to be the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM emp LEFT JOIN salary ON emp.emp_id = salary.emp_id;
```

This will return all employees along with their `emp_sal`, which will be `NULL` if it's not in the `salary` table.

Comment: thanks for help , but i just updated my q , can u help me again

Comment: @user3904968 Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If what I read is right, you want to get the employee name and salary, returning all employees regardless if they have an entry in `salary`. If that is correct, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_name, 
    e.emp_id, 
    s.emp_sal
FROM
    emp AS e
    LEFT JOIN salary AS s ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id
```

If, however, you only wanted the employees with an entry in the `salary` table, change `LEFT JOIN` to be `INNER JOIN`.